# Can you Recommend me generics name which is used in service of controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i know this convention of generics

E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)

K - Key

N - Number

T - Type

V - Value

S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

But i don't know it when I named service of generics in spring
For example,this abstract class is used when Datas do select, insert, update, delete in controller
**i want to name B body of reqeust and RB to name body of response** Is it okay?
Can you Recommend me generics name which is used in service of controller ?

```
 public abstract class AbstractService<B, RB> {

    public abstract RB doInsert(B entity);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class FruitInsertService extends AbstractService<FruitEntity, String[]> {


    @Override
    public String[] doInsert(FruitEntity entity) {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fruit")
public class FruitInsertController {

    @Autowired
    FruitInsertService fruitInsertService;

    @PostMapping("/insert.do")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> insertFruit(FruitEntity fruitEntity){
    
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fruitInsertService.doInsert(fruitEntity));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go strictly by the book and the common convention, you may go for below. Note in your writeup you have already mentioned that T should be used for Type and S for Second Type etc..

`public abstract class AbstractService<T, S>`

However, if you want to make it more explicit and avoid any possible confusion with Second Types etc.., you could use convention like below which explains the context of usage as well.

`public abstract class AbstractService<ReqT, ResT>`

Optionally, you may also want to make these look like classes to depict more specific inputs, and go for something like below.

`public abstract class AbstractService<Content, Response>`

All options would work, but its usually driven by the convention being followed in your project/enterprise. First one is probably what you are looking for here.

Please note, while Java will not be unhappy with 2nd and 3rd options mentioned here, if you are a stickler for Code Quality and Static Analysis, Sonar will be unhappy with using such names. It expects you to use either S, T convention, or you may also choose T1, T2 to indicate the two types.

`public abstract class AbstractService<T1, T2>`

Between S, T and T1, T2, you should probably go for the S, T convention. Sonar expects type names to follow the pattern `'^[A-Z][0-9]?$'`

Hope this helps you decide. If you are confused with options, you can simply go with the 1st one.